# What happens when you shake a coke bottle too hard?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, home-experiment

I've been thinking about this recently :
what happens when you shake a coke bottle too hard?
I know that shaking a coke bottle and opening it would release the coke. So if I tried it, what would happen : would the bottle explode to the chemical reaction, the lid to pop off due to the chemical reaction or would it stay put until the lid opens?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/704190/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shaking the bottle doesn’t raise the pressure inside the bottle (you can test this with a can; the side pushes in the same before and after shaking)

Instead, shaking puts lots of little bubbles into the liquid. When you decrease the pressure by opening the top, those many bubbles can grow very quickly. That drives up the foam and liquid above them.

Comment: Bob, that doesn't answer my original question which of the following do you think will happen

Comment: The pressure stays the same: no lid popping, no explosion.

Comment: would the bottle explode to the chemical reaction, the lid to pop off due to the chemical reaction or would it stay put until the lid opens?

Comment: sorry, Bob I didn't read your comment